# OpenSeadragon constructor Cannot read appendChild of null

Tags: angular, appendchild, openseadragon, ngzone

Sometimes when I use the Openseadragon contructor I get this error.

[image]

There isn't a regular pattern to reproduce the error, maybe 2 or 3 times on 10 contructor will go in this error.
My simple code is the following

[image]

And it also occurs when if I use ngZone for performance like official guide suggets

[image]

Do someone have a solution? It is a known bug or do I missing somthing?

Github ref link [here](https://github.com/openseadragon/openseadragon/issues/2396)